# Ansible ad-hoc commands don't work with Cisco devices

Tags: ansible, cisco

I have newly installed Ubuntu server with Ansible.
I try to use Ansible in my network, but it fails for me just from the beginning

`10.102.249.3` is a router

```
zab@UbuntuSrv:/etc/ansible$ ansible 10.102.249.3 -a "conf t" --ask-pass -vvv       
SSH password: 
<10.102.249.3> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: zab
<10.102.249.3> REMOTE_MODULE command conf t
<10.102.249.3> EXEC ['sshpass', '-d6', 'ssh', '-C', '-tt', '-q', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/home/zab/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o', 'Port=22', '-o', 'GSSAPIAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PubkeyAuthentication=no', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '10.102.249.3', "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1412930091.8-230458979934210 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1412930091.8-230458979934210 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1412930091.8-230458979934210'"]
<10.102.249.3> PUT /tmp/tmpZUkRET TO Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1412930091.8-230458979934210 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1412930091.8-230458979934210 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1412930091.8-230458979934210'"/command
10.102.249.3 | FAILED => failed to transfer file to Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1412930091.8-230458979934210 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1412930091.8-230458979934210 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1412930091.8-230458979934210'"/command:

Connection to 10.102.249.3 closed by remote host.
Connection closed

zab@UbuntuSrv:/etc/ansible$ ansible 10.102.249.3 -m ping  --ask-pass -vvv         
SSH password: 
<10.102.249.3> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: zab
<10.102.249.3> REMOTE_MODULE ping
<10.102.249.3> EXEC ['sshpass', '-d6', 'ssh', '-C', '-tt', '-q', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/home/zab/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o', 'Port=22', '-o', 'GSSAPIAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PubkeyAuthentication=no', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '10.102.249.3', "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1412930136.7-170302836431532 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1412930136.7-170302836431532 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1412930136.7-170302836431532'"]
<10.102.249.3> PUT /tmp/tmpOPuOWh TO Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1412930136.7-170302836431532 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1412930136.7-170302836431532 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1412930136.7-170302836431532'"/ping
10.102.249.3 | FAILED => failed to transfer file to Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1412930136.7-170302836431532 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1412930136.7-170302836431532 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1412930136.7-170302836431532'"/ping:

Connection to 10.102.249.3 closed by remote host.
Connection closed
```

**Update:**
What is wrong with my playbook? 
I get `ERROR: raw is not a legal parameter at this level in an Ansible Playbook`

```
---
- hosts: testsw
  remote_user: zab
  tasks: 
  - name: copy tftp run
    raw: copy tftp://10.1.78.153/test running-config
```

**Update2:** Thanks, now it plays. But it can't connect to switches (cisco 3750, cisco 2960). I can make ssh from this server. Ansible connects to second switch and we can se banner. I remember that Ansible pushes python scripts to remote host. But now I use raw module inside playbook. Does it work in such way?

```
ansible-playbook test.yml --ask-pass
SSH password: 

PLAY [testsw] ***************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
fatal: [10.0.100.61] => failed to transfer file to Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413965089.88-16456712970308 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413965089.88-16456712970308 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413965089.88-16456712970308'"/setup:

Connection to 10.0.100.61 closed by remote host.
Connection closed

fatal: [10.0.100.60] => failed to transfer file to Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413965089.85-196216747271106 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413965089.85-196216747271106 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1413965089.85-196216747271106'"/setup:

C Authorized access only!
 Disconnect IMMEDIATELY if you are not an authorized network administrator!
channel_by_id: 2: bad id: channel free
client_input_channel_req: channel 2: unknown channel
Connection to 10.0.100.60 closed by remote host.
Connection closed


TASK: [copy tftp run] ********************************************************* 
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting


PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/zab/test.retry

10.0.100.60                : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   
10.0.100.61                : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Comment: You indentation was wrong. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're sending a `conf t`, I suppose you're trying to talk to a Cisco router.
This won't work, since Ansible pushes python scripts that are executed on the remote host.

The only way to do something is to use the `raw` module, like so :

```
ansible cat -m raw -a 'show clock' --ask-pass -c paramiko
SSH password: 
cat | success | rc=0 >>

11:11:51.676 METDST Fri Oct 10 2014
```

I have to use paramiko too for the connection.
Don't even think about sending confing this way : each call to module will reopen a ssh connection, so you can not send a config using consecutive ansible commands.

The best you can do is to `copy tftp://.... startup-config`, by sending a config file to a tftp server first.

This is however quite easy to orchestrate with ansible.

Good luck.

Comment: please have a look at Update2. If you can share your configuration it would be nice.

Comment: you have to use paramiko (see `-c paramiko` above)

Comment: Now I have problem with authentication on devices. It worked before (without playbook), now when I make `ansible all -m raw -a 'show clock' --ask-pass -c paramiko -vvv` I get `kh.tb03 | FAILED => FAILED: Authentication failed.` I double checked password, I copy-pasted it. Debug on cisco says that method ACS is picked, but I don't see anything in ACS failed or passed attemtps. SSH to devices from server works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

For Update2: you need to disable gathering facts for Cisco devices as this is not supported.

```
---
- hosts: testsw
  remote_user: zab
  gather_facts: false
  tasks: 
  - name: copy tftp run
    raw: copy tftp://10.1.78.153/test running-config
```

The raw module just sends the string through ssh as it is written, this is typically how I function with Ansible + Cisco devices.

For openssh to work with Cisco devices I usually setup my local .ssh/config like the following:

```
Host *
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
  ServerAliveInterval 120
  ServerAliveCountMax 2
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPersist 60s
```

Comment: Hi can I ask have you ever managed to use this configuration to get multi line raw commands to work with Cisco or Juniper devices?

Answer (score 2):

Ansible now support cisco ios device in core module. You could have a look here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ios_config_module.html

here is a simple example.

1. site.yml

```
    - name: play show commands and change running-config on cisco ios device
    hosts:
    - cisco
    gather_facts: no
    connection: local
    roles:
      - cisco
```

2. tasks/main.yml

```
    ---
    - name: define provider
      set_fact:
        provider:
          host: "{{inventory_hostname}}"
          username: "{{username}}"
          password: "{{password}}"

    - name: run show commands with ios_command
      ios_command:
        provider: "{{provider}}"
        commands:
          - show version
          - show ip interface brief
          - show inventory
          - show ntp association
      register: show_result

    - debug: var=show_result.stdout_lines

    - name: change ntp server with ios_config
      ios_config:
        provider: "{{ provider }}"
        authorize: yes
        lines:
          - ntp server {{ntpsrv01}}
          - ntp server {{ntpsrv02}}
        replace: block
        match: line
        before:
          - no ntp server {{ntpsrv03}}
          - no ntp server {{ntpsrv04}}
        force: true

    - name: run show ntp association after change with ios_config
      ios_command:
        provider: "{{ provider }}"
        commands:
          - show ntp association
      register: after_change_ntp

    - debug: var=after_change_ntp.stdout_lines

    - name: change syslog server with ios_template
      ios_template:
        host: "{{inventory_hostname}}"
        username: "{{username}}"
        password: "{{password}}"
        src: config.j2
        force: true

    - name: run "show running | include logging host" after change made
      ios_command:
        provider: "{{ provider }}"
        commands:
          - show running | include logging host
      register: syslogsrv_list

    - debug: var=syslogsrv_list.stdout_lines

    - name: write running-config to startup-config
      ios_command:
        provider: "{{ provider }}"
        commands:
          - write
      register: write_output

    - debug: var=write_output.stdout_lines
```